# NPAPI for Google Chrome Extension in Objective-C example?

Tags: objective-c, macos, google-chrome-extension, npapi

I searched all Internet but can't find any example of working NPAPI plugin (in Objective-C for Mac OS) which is called from Google Chrome Extension. I'm very want to get such Xcode example, please help if someone have one.

Answer (score 2):

You don't actually need one example plugin that does all those things; how an NPAPI plugin is implemented internally has no effect on how it's called from the browser. The API is always the same C API.

Start with a simple Mac plugin (like [this one](http://code.google.com/p/npapi-sdk/source/browse/#svn/trunk/samples/mac-basic)), change the .c to a .m (or add new .m files), and use as much Objective-C as you like in the implementation.

Then once that's built, follow [the instructions for using an NPAPI plugin in a Chrome extension](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/npapi.html).